# How to display an animated svg in react-native?

Tags: react-native, svg

How do I display an animated svg (with keyframes) in react-native? Currently I can only display a static SVG.

It appears react-native-svg is only able to display static svgs.

Here is a snippet of the SVG:

```
const xml = `<svg
        version="1.1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="64"
        height="64"
        viewbox="0 0 64 64">
    <defs>
        <filter id="blur" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="4" result="offsetblur"/>
            <feComponentTransfer>
                <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.05"/>
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
        <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
/*
** CLOUDS
*/
@keyframes am-weather-cloud-2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px);
       -moz-transform: translate(0px,0px);
        -ms-transform: translate(0px,0px);
            transform: translate(0px,0px);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(2px,0px);
       -moz-transform: translate(2px,0px);
        -ms-transform: translate(2px,0px);
            transform: translate(2px,0px);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px);
       -moz-transform: translate(0px,0px);
        -ms-transform: translate(0px,0px);
            transform: translate(0px,0px);
  }
}

.am-weather-cloud-2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: am-weather-cloud-2;
     -moz-animation-name: am-weather-cloud-2;
          animation-name: am-weather-cloud-2;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
          animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
     -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

...

<SvgXml xml={xml} width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Answer (score 1):

My advise would be checking out react native lottie package, if you can convert your animation to the lottie files json then it will be easy to display